# LSTM for classification

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm, rnn

I am new to neural networks and I want to use LSTM to classify the on/off state of devices based on power values. In my training dataset, I have power values, device one (0,1), and device 2 (0,1). 0 for no change in the state and 1 for when they are switched on and off. The testing dataset has only power values. The dataset has a temporal dependency, so I decided to use LSTM. Now, I am not able to prepare my data for this neural network. Could anyone please give me some tips/ guidelines or link to any resource? I would be thankful!

This is what my training data looks like;

[image]

```py
def df_to_X_y_2(df, window_size = 12):
    df_np = df.to_numpy() 
    X = []
    y = []
    for i in range(window_size, len(df)):
        row = [[a] for a in df_np[i-window_size:i,0]]
        label = df_np[i-1,1:]
        X.append(row)
        y.append(label)
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

I am using Keras and this is the model I came up with;

```py
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(InputLayer((12, 1)))
model1.add(LSTM(64))
model1.add(Dense(32, 'relu'))
model1.add(Dense(2, 'sigmoid'))

cp1 = ModelCheckpoint('models/model1/', save_best_only=True)
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])

model1.fit(X2, y2, epochs=10, callbacks=[cp1])
```

This is not giving me good results. There are a total of 12 ones (True) values for device 1 and 4 Trues for device 2 in my test data but it is not predicting one even once.

I tried this model as well but no luck.

```py
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(InputLayer((12, 1)))
# model2.add(LSTM(64, activation = 'tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid'))
model2.add(LSTM(64))
```

If someone's interested this is the detailed explanation of the task.

The task at hand involves developing a Non-Intrusive Load Monitoring (NILM) program that
classifies continuous aggregate power loads into switching events. The
dataset contains aggregate power loads and switching events for specific appliances.
The goal is to analyze the data and develop an algorithm that accurately classifies the
continuous aggregate power into switching events.
The classification algorithm needs to identify the patterns in the
continuous aggregate power, and accurately
predicts switching events.

Comment: give us more information. Are you using Keras or PyTorch? Can you provide the network so we inspect it?

Comment: @Memristor, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: If you want to know when the switching is ON/OFF I would take the values from `power` directly before jumping to the LSTM.

Comment: could you please elaborate? Did you mean that LSTM is not the right choice of the algorithm here? If this is the case, what other neural networks should I look into?

Comment: If you are not getting results you should indeed try another approach. From a physics perspective (maybe your problem is more complicated, then I'm wrong) switches have a threshold so that when the voltage is greater they become ON, the rest of the time it is OFF by default, so maybe starting with a fully connected or a Decision Tree (or even a linear regression) can be a better approach.

Comment: Is your data balanced? I mean, how many ON do you have for `switch1` vs. OFF (same question for `switch2`).

Comment: 19 ONs in ~200,000 datapoints

Comment: Totally unbalanced. Either try to understand the physics of the problem or maybe use anomaly detection tools.